How to Play from Multiple files Playlist on Plyr
I am using Plyr to Stream Two M3U8 Audios
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/1.8.2/plyr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.js"></script>

and
<script id="rendered-js" >
(function () {
  var audio = document.querySelector('#player');

  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('song1.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(audio);
  }

  plyr.setup(audio);
})();
    </script>
<script id="rendered-js" >
(function () {
  var audio = document.querySelector('#player');

  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('song2.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(audio);
  }

  plyr.setup(audio);
})();
    </script>

But its both players are Simultaneously playing.
How to make switching between two or three Players...
Kindly Let me know..
In Selector,
used
 var audio = document.querySelector('#player');
 var audio = document.querySelector('#player2');

